# When using the 960 Grid System, How to have a column that's 181px?

Tags: css, html, grid

I want to use the 960 Grid System and create a grid that's 981px using:

http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs01.php?GridWidth=981&GridColumns=3&GridMarginLeft=20&GridMarginRight=20

Problem is I don't see how I can make a left column with a width of 181. It seems that with the grid system I'm stuck with 287. Is that true? THoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you shouldnt have a grid of only 3 columns. Dont think of a single column as a column in your layout (ie. main, right, left). Instead it is the smallest possible unit of horizontal measure. so you might have a left side bar that is 4 columns, a left sidebar of 3 columns and a main area of 5 columns.

That said if you need to have specific widths already embedded ina  design youve been handed then using a grid framework probably isnt a good idea. Normally you would have the designer design to the grid you plan on using, or revise the design to snap to the grid. No matter what you do you may not be able to get a grid with a "n columns = 181px" measurement.

Comment: thanks. I'm still trying to wrap my head around. Would you have time to show a quick & dirty example of a grid layout with the following column dimentions? Left: 181px, Center: 533px, Right: 244px?

Comment: @Roger: I think Marcel has it covered in his answer and comment responses. Bottomline - when you use a grid you throw arbitrary sizing out - you need to work with the grid sizes - a column being the smallest unit of measure and all primary blocks being a multiple of the width. Thus its better if you design to the grid in the first place or can rework the design to snap it into the grid as part of the "production art" process.

Answer (score 1):

You could always 'break' out of the 960gs and create a div inside a column (that div would then be a set width). Make sure to account for that div, clear it properly, and you will get your desired width.  But really you should be utilizing the grid system, or none at all if you need to hack up the whole page.

ex:

```
<div class="prefix_1 grid_3">
 <div style="width: 181px; float: left;">
  example
 </div>
</div>
```

Or `position: relative;` etc; however you want to break out of frames (whatever fits your setup I mean).

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a grid system](http://grids.heroku.com/grid?column_width=181&column_amount=5&gutter_width=15) with columns `181px` wide that has a full width of `981px`. The reason it matches your width requirement is that one outer edge is `1px` wider than the other side. Knock that `1px` off and you end up with a nicely rounded full width of `980px`;

Comment: Thanks but that has very strange padding? 14px instead of 20px.

Comment: @RogerTreem: Then [this is the only way you can really go](http://grids.heroku.com/grid?column_width=181&column_amount=5&gutter_width=20) if you wish to use a grid system.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the grid system isn't the way to go.

Comment: @RogerTreem: I thought that would be the case. If you're already decided on the widths of columns and they aren't evenly divisible by each other, forget about working to a grid.